# SQL Query to find out records created in last hour (working with epoch datetime format)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out the records created in last one hour.

Here is my WHERE clause

```
WHERE Create_DateTime > (DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETDATE())-(3600))
```

The Create_DateTime is in epoch integer format.

It does run but I do not get the expected result.

Anyone knows a proper query for this?

Thanks

---

I am not very familiar with SQL functions but I tried GETUTCDATE() in place of GETDATE() and it gave me the expected result.

GETDATE() is giving me the time that is 8 hours earlier from my current time. I am in PST.

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 

Create_DateTime > DATEDIFF(minute,CAST(yourvarcharcolumn as datetime),GETDATE())<=60
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work ?

```
select * from myTable where Datediff(minute, Create_DateTime, getutcdate()) <= 60
```