# Return rows from the past hour with epoch timestamp

Tags: sql-server

I have a database column representing an epoch time as a `decimal(20)`. I'd like to run a query returning all rows where that timestamp is in the past hour. I found [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110790/sql-query-to-find-out-records-created-in-last-hour-working-with-epoch-datetime), and tried modeling my query the same way:

```
select * 
  from logging_event 
 where level_string = 'ERROR' 
   and logger_name like 'my.logger.prefix.%'
   and Datediff(minute, logging_event.timestmp, getutcdate()) <= 60;
```

but I'm seeing

> ```
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the data in the column logging_event.timestmp? What happens if you replace it by getutcdate()?

Comment: Try casting logging_event.timestmp as datetime2. 
`Datediff(minute, cast(getdate() as datetime2), getutcdate()) <= 60;`

Comment: @EricHauenstein Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Explicit conversion from data type decimal to datetime2 is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just convert the decimal column containing the epoch time to a DateTime. You will have to do this manually.

Try the following query:

```
select * 
  from logging_event 
 where level_string = 'ERROR' 
   and logger_name like 'my.logger.prefix.%'
   and Datediff(
        minute, 
        dateadd(s, logging_event.timestmp, '19700101'), 
        getutcdate()
       ) <= 60;
```

[MSDN DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186819.aspx)

> number   Is an expression that can be resolved to an int that is added
>   to a datepart of date. User-defined variables are valid.

The value of `logging_event.timestmp` has to be able to fit into an `INT`. The max value of an `INT`is 2,147,483,647.

Try converting `logging_event.timestmp` to minutes or hours etc. until the value is 2,147,483,647 or lower.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I read epoch, then promptly forgot it when I wrote my comment.

Comment: @JodyT Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: Hm. Since I'm looking at a 20-digit decimal representing milliseconds since the epoch, I needed to replace logging_event.timestmp with (logging_event.timestmp / 1000).